# htacces redirect 301 old subdirectory to a new subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I´m trying to redirect some old subdirectories on my htaccess but I have troubles to succeed

my code looks like this:

```
Redirect 301  /oldsection/oldsubsection  mysite.com/newsection
Redirect 301  /oldsection        mysite.com/newsection/newsubsection
```

I tried a lot of things but it doesnt works, could someone help me?

Comment: thanks for answer. I tried that way but I have the same result (no redirection), can I debug the .htaccess? or do it in other way?

Answer (score 0):

Use `RedirectMatch` instead for its regex capabilities and target can have just the URLs without domain names:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/oldsection/oldsubsection/?$ /newsection
RedirectMatch 301 ^/oldsection/?$ /newsection/newsubsection
```